# ElasticSearch index deletion

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm using Java API to delete old indexes from ElasticSearch.

```
Client client = searchConnection.client

DeleteIndexResponse delete = client.admin().indices().delete(new DeleteIndexRequest('location')).actionGet();
```

During deletion cluster goes red for a minute and not indexing new data - reason "missing indices/replicas etc".

How I can tell ElasticSearch that I'm going to delete them to prevent "red state"?

Comment: What other processes do you have which contribute data into ES?

Comment: Another process - inserting data to new indexes

Answer (score 0):

You could use [aliases](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html) in order to abstract from the real indices underneath. The idea would be to read from an alias and write to an alias instead. That way you can create a new index, swap the write alias to the new index (so that the indexing process is not disrupted) and then delete the old index. Process-wise, it would go like this:

**Context:** Your current `location` index has the `location_active` alias and the indexing process writes to the `location_active` alias instead of directly to the `location` index.

**Step 1:** Create the new `location_112015` index

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/location_112015
```

**Step 2:** Swap the `location_active` alias from the "old" `location` index to the "new" one created in step 1

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_aliases' -d '{
    "actions" : [
        { "remove" : { "index" : "location", "alias" : "location_active" } },
        { "add" : { "index" : "location_112015", "alias" : "location_active" } }
    ]
}'
```

Note that this operation is atomic, so if the indexing process keeps sending new documents to `location_active`, it will be transparent for it and no docs will be lost, no errors will be raised.

**Step 3:** Remove the old index

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/location
```

**Step 4:** Rinse and repeat as often as needed

Note: these operations can easily be performed with the Java client library as well.

Comment: I write to new index everyday, and removing indexes older than 1 week. When I execute DELETE - cluster goes down for a minute. Can I change somehow priority of deletion - so it will not affect that much cluster indexing rate?

Comment: I'm deleting around 40 indexes everyday, one by one - approximately 130 mil events in these

Comment: The deletion being a synchronous operation, I'm not sure how prioritizing would help here, when you delete the index, it's gone, there's no way to schedule a deletion to happen when no indexing occurs. The alias solution I described above allows you to do both (delete and index) in a transparent way without downtime.

Comment: I don't write to the index which I'm deleting, and using aliases also. when I execute DELETE - it takes 6-7k IOPS, and app which is sending data - can't send any data during deletion time. Looks like I need to add some sleep time after each index is removed

Comment: Have you tried to close the index first and then delete it?

Comment: Nope, going to try it, or add check for cluster state - and delete next index when state is back to green